# Откуда оператор delete[] узнает сколько байт следует освободить

Tags: c++

Что-то я задумался о том, что не понимаю одной вроде тривиальной вещи.

```
int *p = new int[20];
delete[] p;
```

Откуда оператор `delete[]` узнает о том, что нужно освободить именно `20 * sizeof(int)` байт?

Что произойдет в результате выполнения следующего кода:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *p1 = new int[16];
    int *p2 = p1;
    p1 = new int[20];
    cout << p1 << " --- " << p2 << " --- " << p1 - p2 << endl;
    delete[] p1;
    delete[] p2;
    return 0;
}
```

и корректен ли он вообще?
Вывод на консоль:

```
0x3d2b30 --- 0x3d2ae8 --- 18
```

Т.е. между выделенными областями памяти есть еще 64 разряда. Последнее число всегда четное, и минимум на 2 больше, чем размер первого массива.

Еще один эксперимент (выше было на Win7/Qt/mingw), теперь Ubunto14.04/Qt/g++:

```
int main()
{
    int *p1 = new int[20];
    int *p2 = p1;
    p1 = new int[20];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        p1[i] = 0xAAAAAAAA;
        p2[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
    cout << "Pointers: " << p1 << " --- " << p2 << " --- " << p1 - p2 << endl;
    cout << "shifted pinters: " << p1 - 1 << " --- " << p1 - 2 << endl;
    cout << "values in skipped space: " << hex << *(p1-1) << " --- " << *(p1-2)
                                    << " --- " << *(p1-3) << " --- " << *(p1-4) << endl;
    cout << "values from p2 memory: " << hex << *(p1-5) << " --- " << *(p1-6)
                                    << " --- " << *(p1-7) << " --- " << *(p1-8) << endl;
    delete[] p1;
    delete[] p2;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
Pointers: 0x1ebd070 --- 0x1ebd010 --- 24
shifted pinters: 0x1ebd06c --- 0x1ebd068
values in skipped space: 0 --- 61 --- 0 --- 0
values from p2 memory: ffffffff --- ffffffff --- ffffffff --- ffffffff
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Оператор `new[]` сохраняет информацию о количестве элементов массива. Оператор `delete[]` достает эту информацию и вызывает деструкторы у элементов.

Компилятор может сгенерировать код для этих операторов следующим образом:

```
// Исходный код
struct A {
    A();
    ~A();
};

A* a = new A[10];
delete[] a;

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Код, который генерирует компилятор (см. примечания ниже)

// A* a = new A[10];
A* a;
{
    // выделяем память
    void* _mem = malloc(sizeof(int) + 10 * sizeof(A));
                     // ^- выделяем дополнительную память для размера массива
    int* _size_ptr = (int*)_mem;
    *_size_ptr = 10; // сохраняем размер
    A* a = (A*)&_size_ptr[1]; // "a" указывает на память за сохраненным размером массива
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        ::operator new(a + i) A; // вызываем конструкторы
}

// delete[] a;
{
    // перемещаем указатель на начало выделенной памяти
    int* _size_ptr = (int*)a - 1;
    for (int i = *_size_ptr - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        a[i].~A(); // вызываем деструкторы
    // удаляем память
    free(_size_ptr);
}
```

Примечание 1: На самом деле вместо `malloc` и `free` вызываются функции `void* operator new[](size_t bytes)` и `void operator delete[](void*)`. Но т.к. они вызывают что-то похожее на malloc/free, то в контексте данного вопроса этим можно пренебречь.

Примечание 2: Для обработки исключений, компилятор будет генерировать try-catch блок для `new[]`.

Comment: Дополню вопрос некоторым экспериментальным подтверждением

Comment: Т.е. даже при применении оператора `delete[]` к копии указателя, данный оператор обратится к соответствующей памяти (которая была выделенна одновременно с данными и на которую где-то в области данных хранится еще один указатель, ну или как-то так), которая отвечает за количество изначально выделенных байт по такому указателю, в итоге, учтет размер изначально выделенной памяти при удалении?

Answer (score 5):

Когда вы выделяете память к куче, аллокатор знает, сколько памяти было выделено. Эта информация находится в "голове" сегмента перед самой информацией. Когда необходимо очистить память, деалокатор берёт эту мета-информацию и удаляет данные. Хотя, это вроде как зависит от компилятора. Надо читать [документацию](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#num-elems-in-new-array).

По поводу же второй части не совсем уверен, давно с C++ не работал, но проблемы не вижу, вроде всё корректно:

```
int *p1 = new int[30]; // выделяется 30 элементов, указатель p1 ссылается на эту область
int *p2 = p1;          // указатель p2 ссылается на ту же область памяти
p1 = new int[20];      // выделяется 20 элементов, указатель p1 теперь ссылается на эту область
delete[] p1;           // удаляем 20 элементов
delete[] p2;           // удаляем 30 элементов
```