# Откуда C/C++ знает сколько надо освободить памяти, если не знает размер массива?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, malloc, calloc

В C/C++ для того чтобы обработать массив нужно знать его размер. Соответственно нужно всегда этот размер "помнить" и протаскивать во все функции обработки в качестве аргумента. Например:

```
void foo(int* arr, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = i * i;
    }
}
```

Но при освобождении ресурсов знать размер почему-то необязательно. Можно просто вызвать `free(arr)` если память выделялась через `malloc()` или `calloc()`. Или можно использовать оператор `delete[] arr;` если память выделялась через оператор `new int[n]`.

Вопрос откуда C/C++ знает сколько надо освободить памяти, если не знает размер массива? Функция `free()` и оператор `delete[]` не принимают в качестве аргументов размер массива, а только указатель на массив. А если C/C++ может каким-то образом вычислить размер, то зачем его постоянно "таскать" с собой в отдельной переменной?

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474727/10105

Comment: Понятие «размерность» не является синонимом понятия «размер». «Размерность» — количество _измерений_, «размер» — количество _элементов_.

Comment: В GNU есть функция [malloc_usable_size](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc_usable_size), но она может возвращать большую величину, чем вы запрашивали в malloc, создавая массив. Так что, тащите всюду его размер...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Все это - детали реализации.

- `malloc / free`

  В популярных реализациях `malloc` обычно записывает размер выделенного блока в начало выделенного блока. Возвращенный вам указатель обычно указывает на память сразу за этим записанным размером. `free` знает, где искать размер блока, и извлекает его именно оттуда.
- `new / delete`

  По умолчанию обычные `new` и `delete` (без `[]`) просто делегируют запросы на выделение и освобождение сырой памяти в тот же самый `malloc` и `free` или их аналоги, через посредство `operator new` и `operator delete`.
- `new[] / delete[]`

  При работе с массивами объектов *с тривиальными деструкторами* `new[]` и `delete[]` фактически ведут себя точно так же: вызывают в конечном итоге `malloc` с правильно вычисленным общим размером массива и вызывают `free` для освобождения памяти.

  При работе с массивами объектов *с нетривиальными деструкторами* все несколько сложнее: `new[]` запрашивает от `malloc` немножко больше памяти и дополнительно записывает в начало выделенного  блока точное количество элементов создаваемого массива, а `delete[]` потом извлекает это количество и вызывает правильное количество деструкторов<sup>†</sup>.

  Допустим, если у вас есть какой-то класс `MyNonTrivialClass` размером в 9 байт с нетривиальным деструктором, то выполнение

  ```
  MyNonTrivialClass *p = new MyNonTrivialClass[17];
  ```

  приведет к формированию блока памяти со следующей внутренней структурой

  ```
  +-----+-----+------+------+------
  | 176 |  17 | p[0] | p[1] | ...
  +-----+-----+------+------+------
     ^     ^  ^
     |     |  |
     |     |  p - полученный вами указатель
     |     |
     |     поле типа `size_t` (8 байт), записано `new[]`
     |
     поле типа `size_t` (8 байт), записано `malloc` 
     `new[]` запросил 161 байт = 17 * 9 + 8, размер выровнен до границы 16 байт
  ```

  Конкретные значения могут отличаться, но общая идея обычно в популярных реализациях именно такая.

  --

  <sup>†</sup> Кроме нетривиальных деструкторов в языке есть еще одна ситуация, которая обычно заставляет `new[]` сохранять в начале выделенного блока количество элементов массива: когда создается массив объектов, содержащих перегруженный `operator delete[](void *, std::size_t)`, т.е. функцию освобождения памяти со вторым параметром типа `std::size_t`. При освобождении памяти реализации обязаны передавать через этот параметр то же самое значение, которое передавалось в соответствующий вызов `operator new[]`. Для этого им нужно хранить точный размер массива.

  Что характерно, Microsoft Visual Studio по сей день (VS2019) игнорирует это требование языка, не сохраняет размер массива и передает в такой `operator delete[]` некорректное значение размера.

См. также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770300/182825

Comment: Скажите, а есть ли смысл в записи количества элементов, если известен размер одного элемента? Или есть какие-то тонкости?

Comment: @selya: Не совсем понимаю вопрос. Во-первых, `malloc` может запросто округлить размер выделяемого блока в большую сторону и сохранить именно округленный размер. В такой ситуации деление сохраненного размера всего блока на размер элемента не обязательно точно совпадет с фактическим размером массива. Во-вторых, механизм распределения сырой  памяти можно запросто перегрузить и `delete[]` вообще потеряет доступ к размеру блока. Поэтому при необходимости размер массива `new[]` всегда сохраняет отдельно и самостоятельно.

Comment: просто мне кажется, что это, по крайней мере, не логично - тягать ещё количество элементов хвостиком. Мне кажется, конкретная реализация вполне себе должна знать, как там и что округляется, и вопрос о записи ещё и количества элементов там не стоит...

Comment: @selya: При чем здесь "знает"? Если размер округлился, то восстановить количество уже не получится, независимо от того, "знает" ли реализация про округление или не знает. И, еще раз, не забываем, что механизм выделения сырой памяти - прегружаем.

Comment: Простой эксперимент покажет вам эти размеры: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8fa350da0f46bd2

Comment: Т.е. для не тривиального записывается 29 - т.е. количество элементов, а для тривиального что-то другое - к примеру, размер выделенного блока, так?

Comment: @selya: Я же написал: первый размер записывается всегда `malloc`-ом, второй размер записывается `new[]` не всегда. В первом примере виден и размер блока, и отдельно размер массива. Во втором и третьем примере `new[]` вообще ничего не записывал, а `129` - это размер блока, записанный `malloc`-ом. Почему именно `129` - спрашивайте у реализации.

Answer (score 13):

Вообще говоря, это знает менеджер памяти. Например, где-нибудь перед началом выделенного блока имеется какая-то служебная область, в которой указано, чего и сколько выделено.

Только вот это - дело менеджера памяти, который к языку отношение имеет "постольку поскольку" - это проблемы конкретной реализации, что и как делать. Так что *язык* размерность вычислить не в состоянии.