# Как работает delete[]?

Tags: c++

*Ответ на похожий вопрос* [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796215/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-c-c-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Я могу создать динамический массив

```cpp
int *ptr = new int[20];
```

и после удалить его

```cpp
delete [] ptr;
```

Но у меня тут встал вопрос, откуда delete[] знает размер массива?
Раз он способен удалить весь массив только по указателю на его первый элемент, то могу ли я используя тот же трюк узнать размер абсолютно любого массива?

Comment: Очевидно, когда вы вызываете `new[]`, внутренне этот размер сохраняется.

Comment: Но я так и не понял возможно ли использовать этот механизм записи размера массива перед самим массивом чтоб получить размер массива?
Могу ли я по логике прочитать 8 байт памяти перед началом массива и преобразовать их в int32? Так что ответ там не полный.

Comment: @ВладБочкарёв нет, но что мешает сохранить его отдельно?

Comment: Не нужно заниматься подобными вещами. Это реализация, которая намеренно от вас сокрыта. Используйте `std::vector`, он знает о своём размере, и ничего дополнительно передавать не нужно.

Comment: перешел по всем ссылкам "дубликатам". А там все балуются указателями.... а правильного ответа нет...  о том же _msize (для студии) или malloc_usable_size (для gcc).

Comment: @KoVadim так добавьте этот правильный ответ, если его нет

Comment: там сколько "правильных ответов"....

Comment: @Влад Бочкарёв, если вы создаете массив, значит вы уже знаете размер. Для массива выделяется память по вашей же команде.  Вы хотите что еще знать?...

Comment: если  вы хотите знать размер за пределами функции, где создавался массив, то эта вызываемая функция должна знать(принимать ) или возвращать размер тоже, если возвращает указатель на массив.

Answer (score -2):

Полный ответ есть [тут](https://www.sql.ru/forum/694700/otkuda-delete-array-znaet-skolko-pamyati-nado-vysvobozhdat). Если коротко, то можно узнать размер произвольного массива, но только в текущей реализации. В стандарте написано только, что new[] и delete[] должны создавать и удалять одинаковые участки памяти, а как это сделано - уже не их дело. Потому использовать эту "фичу" можно будет только на конкретной машине в конкретной реализации, что не советуется делать.

Comment: Можно пример без UB как это использовать на какой-нибудь реализации?

Comment: я бы еще хотел услышать от такого "знатока" как sbrk работает. спасибо