# Что будет если передать во free указатель со сдвигом?

Tags: c, память, malloc

Что будет если передать во free указатель со сдвигом?

```
char* arr = malloc(5)
arr+=3;
free(arr)
```

Сможет ли free очистить его, если да, то как дефолтный аллокатор понимает, с какого байта нужно начать?

Comment: [Откуда C/C++ знает сколько надо освободить памяти, если не знает размер массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796215)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Плохо будет. Неопределенное поведение будет.

Скорее всего, просто испортятся данные менеджера памяти, и программа ляжет. Но может и не повезти, и будет продолжать работать, и вылезет эта проблема в другом месте и в другое время...

Comment: Хотя при разумном программировании free() можно обойтись утечкой памяти. (следствие того, что мы должны предполагать худшее и выделять память кратную по крайней мере 8-ми (double и работа в системе с выключнным unaligned))

Comment: Под "разумным программированием" вы понимаете ситуацию когда проблема скрывается от программиста как можно дольше (с тем чтобы максимально затруднить её отладку) ?