# как определить размер знакового массива(в количестве элементов) c++

Tags: c++, массивы

объявлена переменная string, затем вводится её значение, насколько я знаю, в c++ string представляет из себя массив типа char, вопрос состоит в том как определить кол-во элементов после ввода.
Как это сделать с int понятно а char нет, у меня функция sizeof выдает одно и тоже значение байт в независимости от кол ва элементов

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
using namespace std;
int main() {
string msv;
cin>>msv;
}
```

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0+string)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Откуда C/C++ знает сколько надо освободить памяти, если не знает размер массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796215/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-c-c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

[`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) используется для выяснения "статического" размера объекта или типа. Для выяснения "динамического" размера того или иного объекта нужно использовать соответствующие функции, доступные для такого объекта.

В случае с [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) для этого надо использовать [`length` или `size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size).

`sizeof` возвращает одинаковое значение для всех однотипных объектов, т.к. сообщает о суммарном размере структуры данных, например, указателя на данные и целой переменной, которая хранит размер этих динамических данных. Результат `sizeof` не зависит от того, какие выделенные в динамической памяти данные связаны с этим объектом.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно - `msv.size()`.

Есть еще `msv.length()`, который делает то же самое, но им пользуются реже. (Для однообразия - потому что `.size()` работает одинаково хорошо со всеми контейнерами, а `.length()` есть только у `string`.)

`sizeof msv` тут для вас бесполезен. Почему выдает он фиксированное число - поймете, когда почитаете про указатели, `new` и `delete` (тогда станет понятнее, как `string` устроен).